# ILoggerFactory in extension method - lifetime and dispose

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

To create a `ILogger` in extension methods I store a `ILoggerFactory` in a static class

```
public static class ApplicationLogging
{
    public static ILoggerFactory LoggerFactory { get; set; }

    public static ILogger CreateLogger<T>() =>
        LoggerFactory?.CreateLogger<T>();

    public static ILogger CreateLogger(string name) =>
        LoggerFactory?.CreateLogger(name);

}
```

which is set with

```
public void Configure(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
   ...
    ApplicationLogging.LoggerFactory = loggerFactory;
}
```

However, I notice that `ILoggerFactory` gets disposed

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
>   Object name: 'LoggerFactory'.
>       at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactory.CreateLogger(String categoryName)
>       at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger`1..ctor(ILoggerFactory factory)
>       at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactoryExtensions.CreateLogger[T](ILoggerFactory factory)

So is it not correct to store a `ILoggerFactory`? What would be the alternative to access it from extension methods? Store `IServiceProvider` and `GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>` ?

Comment: Why do you need to do logging in an extension method?

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: For the same reasons adding logging elsewhere.

Comment: `ILoggerFactory` is registered as Singleton by default. Built-in DI should not "accidentally" dispose it. When do you get the `ObjectDisposedException`?

Comment: I get it randomly for some requests - my app is a self hosted web API. I do not dispose it anywhere in my code. In fact this msdn article proposes the pattern of keeping a static logger factory https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt694089.aspx

Comment: I think you need to show more of your code. As Ilya said, the logger factory is a singleton and reused everywhere. If you suddenly run into disposed exceptions, something else must be wrong (and no logging should work btw; at least from non singleton services).

Answer (score 1):

`ILoggerFactory` will not be added to DI container by default. You should register it using provided `AddLogging()` extension method.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddLogging()
}
```

that internally simply do

```
services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<ILoggerFactory, LoggerFactory>());
```

---

And anyway, as other comments say - try to use built-in DI container as mush as possible instead of own static classes for dependency resolving.

Comment: How can the built in DI container be used in an extension method?

Comment: it cannot unless you directly pass the service resolver as method's parameter. The main idea that you should not do factory methods as extension methods. Do `ApplicationLogging` class as a simple class with public methods, then register it to DI container as a singleton in `Startup.ConfigureServices` method and then inject it via constructors...

Comment: Thanks Set. Then it comes back to the original question. How can `ApplicationLogging` instance be accessed from the extension method?

Comment: @ubi, ok, so have you tried what you already have but with adding `services.AddLogging();`?

Comment: The issue here is I can't consistently reproduce the issue. Even without `services.AddLogging()` it's working fine - this error appeared randomly in the logs. May be when `GC` comes to collect things it cleans up if it's not in the DI container. Will try with adding it.